# javascript regex search start of every word and following word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regex based on user input that searches the start of every word and the following word (excluding the space) in a string. This is the current code i am using.

```
var ndl = 'needlehay', //user input
re = new RegExp('(?:^|\\s)' + ndl, 'gi'), //searches start of  every word
haystack = 'needle haystack needle second instance';
re.test(haystack); //the regex i need should find 'needle haystack'
```

Any help or suggestions i'd gladly appreciate.

Thanks!

Comment: `haystack.replace(/\s/g, '').indexOf(ndl) != -1`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0qsuqjj3/

Comment: @adeneo - wouldn't that also match `postneedle haystack`?

Comment: @freefaller - it would

Comment: My gut feeling (which is why this is a comment rather than an answer) is that you won't be able to do this with a single regex

Comment: @adeneo - indeed, which is not what the OP is after.  They want *the start of every word and the following word*, which would suggest that the `needle` of `postneedle` shouldn't match?

Comment: There is no `needlehay` in your `haystack`

Comment: thnx for the quick response, wouldn't that expression return any match within the string you remove all the spaces? For eg. searching for 'portarl' from port arlington should return true whilst saport arlington should return false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd iterate over the needle, and try each variation manually

```
function check(needle, haystack) {
    if (haystack.replace(/\s/g, '').indexOf(needle) === 0) return true;

    return needle.split('').some(function(char, i, arr) {
        var m = (i===0 ? '' : ' ') + needle.slice(0,i) +' '+ needle.slice(i);
        return haystack.indexOf(m) != -1;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thnx for the script, this seems to be more thorough.

Comment: I havent used the some method before would i need a polyfill for ie8?

Comment: Yes, `Array.some` would have to be polyfilled, or the function rewritten, to work in IE8, but that shouldn't be very hard.

Comment: I havent had much experience with non latin chars, would this script work?

Comment: As long as it's actual words separated by spaces I don't see why not, all it uses is the length of the string, and the spaces.

Comment: i can't figure out why this function wont work with a string like 'ho chi minh city'. For instance 'hochiminh' works but 'chiminhcity' does not.

Comment: Because that would match the first word and the two following words. You asked for something that matches the first word and **the** following word, not all following words, which would be completely different as that would have to account for any number of spaces

Comment: my bad, should have said 'words'

Comment: @user3299613 - how about something like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/yge3o1ut/**, does that work for you ?

Comment: just tried it with on keyup... http://jsfiddle.net/5unn5jdw/2/..and works exactly as intended. Thanks so much for giving it another shot, i was pulling my hair out trying to figure out how i would write this...

Comment: sorry wrong jsfiddle (my way of trying to do it)...
http://jsfiddle.net/5unn5jdw/3/